# python split by number of times specified

Tags: python

In the following string how can i split the string in the following manner

```
str1="hi\thello\thow\tare\tyou"
str1.split("\t")
n=1
Output=["hi"]

 n=2 
output:["hi","hello"]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
str1.split('\t', n)[:-1]
```

[`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) has an optional second argument which is how many times to split. We remove the last item in the list (the leftover) with the slice.

For example:

```
a = 'foo,bar,baz,hello,world'
print(a.split(',', 2))
# ['foo', 'bar', 'baz,hello,world']  #only splits string twice
print(a.split(',', 2)[:-1])  #removes last element (leftover)
# ['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: why [:-1] should it not be -n

Comment: @Rajeev `[:-1]` removes the last element of the list. It is the same as `[:len(lst)]`. `[:-len(lst)]` removes the whole list. In your case `n` is the length of the list.

Comment: But what if there are more than two or three left overs after splitting

Comment: @Rajeev you've already provided the number of splits you want - Python only will split `n` times, and all you need to do is get rid of the leftover

Comment: yes thats exacly what i want how do u get rid of the left overs [:-1] wont do the job for sure since it removes the last element only

Comment: @Rajeev see the edit (and check out the link to the documentation provided)

Comment: This is such an elegant pythonic response.