# Keep complete string after the 1st split in Python

Tags: python, split

I have strings like:

```
a = "RT@xyz: AI is awesome"
req_ans = " AI is awesome"
b = "RT@xyz: AI: is awesome"
req_ans=" AI: is awesome"
c = "RT@xyz: AI: is: awesome"
req_ans=" AI: is: awesome"
```

So, my requirement is to split the string after 1st column and keep the rest of the string.

I have tried below code but it works for "a" type of string but fails for "b" and "c" type:

```
req_ans= a.split(':')[1]
```

Also tried:

```
req_ans= a.split(':')[1:]
```

But it converts the string into lists but I want the remaining string which is left after the first ":"

[python split by number of times specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235638/python-split-by-number-of-times-specified)
checked the above answer but it converts it to list of words, which I don't want and hence my question is different

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Mentioned how it is different from the question you mentioned. Can you please remove your downvote

Comment: What do you mean *"a list of words"*? What were you expecting?! Precisely how does `.split(':', 1)[1]` fail to solve your problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I have written my expectation at the top of my questions. this .split(':', 1)[1] fails as for string type "b" it will give me only "AI" whereas I want " AI: is awesome". I hop this clears

Comment: I literally tested it with `b`. It gives you exactly what you say you want. So...

Comment: I have also checked and the answer I am getting is "' AI" and not " AI: is awesome" Using Python 2.7

Comment: Then put a [mcve] in the question, but it works fine for me in 3.x and 2.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `str.join` after `str.split`:

```
req_ans = ':'.join(c.split(':')[1:])
# ' AI: is: awesome'
```

The result of `str.split` is a list. If you want all the components after a certain character, without removing the split character, you need to reverse the split after slicing.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem :)

Comment: Why split it and join it back together when you can *not split it*?